# Bad practice to pass IQueryable to ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I might be misunderstanding something about ViewModels here (I'm new to them), but is it a bad practice to pass a static `Get` method an `IQueryable`? I haven't tried this, so I'm not sure if it'll even work, but this is a larger question about the usage of ViewModels.

For example:

```
using (var db = something.Invoke()) {
    var query = some query;
    var data = MyViewModel.Get(query); //pass an IQueryable

    //do something with data
}

class MyViewModel {
    public List<int> Something {get; set;}

    public static MyViewModel Get(IQueryable data) {
        var view = new MyViewModel();
        var list = new List<int>();
        foreach (var d in data) {
            list.Add(d.Column);
        }
        view.Something = list;
        return view;
    }
}
```

It would just seem really redundant to have to map my database to a more generic data structure and then pass that to my ViewModel to do another mapping (like database -> List -> ViewModel). It would be easier if I could just pass in my query and have 100% of the mapping take place in the ViewModel, instead of having that inbetween step (database -> ViewModel).

Comment: Hi. I am actually starting to consider this option too. It's becoming so cumbersome to have to keep making really similar viewmodels over and over again - and because of EF having an IQueryable option, it almost makes sense to me to let the viewmodel constructors create themselves. That is what a "constructor" is for after all... does it really violate SRPrinciple that much I wonder...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have tried using logic in ViewModels, but this is a path to madness.

ViewModels should be POCO - only properties with no (or very basic) logic. All the mapping should be done in controller or even in `QueryHanlder` that is called by a controller. And `QueryHanlder` would take dependency on DB and do required mapping to get from DB data structure to ViewModel.

Responsibility of ViewModel is to carry data from controller to a view (or backwards). And if you get DB or mapping logic into, this is a violation of Single Responsibility Principle.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to have my ViewModels fairly clean and independent of how they are being constructed.

In this situation, I would use a builder or factory pattern to construct your ViewModel, and then that builder/factory can take the dependency on your database.